# iOS 8 Auto height cell not correct height at first load

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I have an iOS 8 application where I have a search results page that each cell is autosized based on the height of a certain label.  However, after the view first loads the cells that are displayed don't autosize.  After you scroll down the cells that follow are sized correctly.  I am wiring up the auto layout constraints in my storyboard.  I have the following code in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //configure tableView so that we use autolayout enabled row heights
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: You can solve this by given this [answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36909723/3818903) Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, I've seen this same problem when making the views and constraints in the storyboard (but not with code added views). Iv'e fixed this by adding this code in the custom cell class,

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview { 
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This could probably go other places, but this method seems to be called only once, so I thought it was a good place to do it.

Comment: Thanks.  This fixed my issue.  Does anyone know if this is a bug, or if it is a symptom of doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I had to remove self layoutIfNeeded in the function where i was loading my datas but this solution works thanks

Comment: Worked -- thanks.  @dennis I would put this in the bug category.

Comment: I had the same issue, but only needed to add the `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` lines in the OP's `viewDidLoad` - I had previously only had settings in Interface Builder (which, at this point, I'm not sure deserves to be capitalized).

Comment: Did not work unfortunately. Any other suggestions? Were you using size classes? Size classes seem to cause issues based on other SO answers.

Comment: This worked for me. It seems like a bug still present in iOS 10. Anyone know the details about why this is an issue or the status of a real fix?

Comment: Thanks for this, also solved my problem with my custom cells not having the correct height when containing a custom view. This bug is still present on iOS 11. (or we are doing something wrong with the views inside the cells)

Comment: Still seeing this in iOS 12. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

The answer from [rdelmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar) did not work for me.

What I have done is added this code:

```
[tableView setNeedsLayout];
[tableView layoutIfNeeded];
[tableView reloadData];
```

after data is fetched and first `[tableView reloadData]` is called, which in my case is located in `viewDidLoad` method of my View Controller.

So result code would be:

```
NSArray *fetchedData = ...

[tableView reloadData]; //Fist table reload
[tableView setNeedsLayout];
[tableView layoutIfNeeded];
[tableView reloadData]; //Second table reload
```

This answer is taken from here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html#comment-1783719287

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! (Y). Works well.

Comment: I can not believe this hack worked, but thanks a bunch! I've been trying to work this one out for ages...

Comment: For me adding `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` to `ViewDidLoad()` did the trick. Thanks for pointing me to this!

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of forcing a `tableView.reloadData()` and `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` in `viewDidLoad`, you can just set your tableView's auto height in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`:

Swift:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by moving assignments to the cell's UILabels' text properties (being the only components that could influence the height calculation in my particular cell) to:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

instead of:

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Before doing this I noticed that the cell height would be correctly calculated if a cell was scrolled momentarily off-screen and then back into view. Most likely because, at that point, the cell had the necessary information regarding the UILabel content determining the final height.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go around this one by not using nibs/storyboards but rather have the layout done programmatically.